# How to add Address space to Azure Rm Virtual Network using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell, azure-resource-manager, azure-virtual-network

I would like to add a new Address space to my existing RM Virtual Network. I can add subnets with command `Add-AzureRmVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig` but unfortunatelly can not find similar command for adding Address space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Get-AzureRmVirtualNetwork` to get the current configuration.  Add your additional address prefixes.  Then, use `Set-AzureRmVirtualNetwork` to apply.

Assuming your virtual network currently has an address prefix of **10.0.0.0/16**, which is the default, you could extend it with additional address prefixes as shown here.

```
# Get existing virtual network
$vnet  = Get-AzureRmVirtualNetwork -Name $vnetName -ResourceGroupName $myResourceGroup

# Add additional address prefixes
$vnet.AddressSpace.AddressPrefixes.Add("10.1.0.0/16")
$vnet.AddressSpace.AddressPrefixes.Add("10.2.0.0/16")
Set-AzureRmVirtualNetwork -VirtualNetwork $vnet
```